# How we see different implementation of same function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to understand how different implementation of same method is done in Spark Scala.

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFr
ame
def createDataFrame(data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A])(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def createDataFrame(rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Here is the different implementation of createDataFrame method? How same method createDataFrame can take different parametets yet output is same - Dataframe?

Comment: It uses a concept called polymorphism - you can read about method overloading and method overriding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of Scala language, similar features are available in many other languages like java, C++ etc.

This feature is called method overloading, it works like this:

```
def myMethod(a:Int,b:Int) = a + b

def myMethod(a:String,B:String) = a + " " + b  

myMethod(1,2) //-----> returns 3, first method is called

myMethod("Hello","world")  //-----> returns "Hello World", second method is called
```

General rules of method overloading:

- Names of all methods should be the same
- Number of parameters/type of parameters or both has to be unique across all methods with same name

Here `createDataFrame` function is overloaded many times to accommodate different scenarios that are used to create a dataframe, to support multiple sources. If you closely look into the source code, you will find that none of those methods which you have highlighted have the same method signature.